# How to do connectivity test from EC2 to VIF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-direct-connect

There is a problem with the connection between AWS resources and I am investigating where the problem is occurring.

Therefore, I would like to do connectivity test through the following route.

EC2->VGW(VirtualPrivateGW)->DXGW(DirectConnectGW)->VIF(VirtualIF)

I connected to EC2 with SessionManager and tried to run the ping command, but could not find the ip address of the VGW/DXGW/VIF.

Comment: Have you tried the reachability analyzer?

Comment: @Paolo Thank you for your response.
I tried to execute it.
The route EC2->ENI->SG->ACL->RTB(RouteTable) was displayed.
In RTB I see the message "RouteTable rtb-xxxx does not have a suitable route to vgw-xxxx".
But I could only run ReachabiltyAnalyzer on the route from EC2 to VGW.
DXGW/VIF were not in the pull-down list.
Is it possible to run ReachabiltyAnalyzer from EC2 to DXGW/VIF?